# How not to go to the next line of file in c

Tags: c, file, line

I am pretty new to C Programming and I'm having problems with my code. My program opens a .txt file and stores the data inside it in a string. After that, the data stored in a string is copied into another .txt file.

```
FILE *  fp = fopen("New.txt", "a");
FILE * fp2 = fopen("File.txt", "r");
while(fgets(str, 100, fp2) != NULL) {
    fputs(str, fp);
}
fclose(fp);
fclose(fp2);
```

Now my problem here is, I want to store the strings in a single line, but my program always goes to the next line. For example, I want the data to be:

```
One Two Three
```

What my code does:

```
One
Two
Three
```

Can you help me? Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`fgets` reads a line, but retains the new-line character at the end. When you write the line, that new line is printed as well. You can remove the new-line character explicitly, for example:

```
int len = strlen(str);

if (len && str[len - 1] == '\n') str[len - 1] = '\0';
```

Alternatively, you could choose another approach: Read the file character-wise with `getc` and print out all characters except new lines with `putc`. (That approach works only if you don't want to do other things that require you to know the contents of each line.)

Comment: I've always had this doubt: Is it better to make `len` with type `size_t` rather than `int` as `strlen` returns `size_t`?

Comment: Well, `size_t` is probably the better choice here: The length can only be zero or positive and it's also the return value of `strlen`.

Comment: So, `size_t==unsigned int`?

Comment: @CoolGuy: `size_t` is an unsigned integer that can hold a valid address: `sizeof(size_t) == sizeof(void *)`. It is `uint32_t` on 32-bit machine and `uint64_t` on 64-bit machines. There's also `ptrdiff_t`, its signed equivalent.